# image cropping selected position using imagick php extension

Tags: php, imagick

Is there a way to crop image of select position in PHP imagick extension?

I use imagick php extenstion with php 5.3+.

If any one knows how to crop position like below please share this with me

I have an image with square of 500px and I want to crop the top 200px (left side) to the bottom 400px rightside.

Please check my examples below.

**Example..**

[Example original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qefCI.png)

**Output..**

[Output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCz5B.png)

Answer (score 4):

I hope this code will help.

```
$mask = new Imagick();
$mask->newimage(500, 500, new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$mask->setimageformat('png');
$polygon = new ImagickDraw();
$polygon->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel('black'));
/*
  You didn't specified from where to start the crop and where to end it, 
  so just assumed those values
*/
$polygon->polygon(array(
    array('x' => 200, 'y' => 0),
    array('x' => 400, 'y' => 0),
    array('x' => 450, 'y' => 500),
    array('x' => 250, 'y' => 500),
    array('x' => 200, 'y' => 0),
));
$mask->drawimage($polygon);
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readimage("Your source image path :) ");
$image->setImageFormat('png');
$image->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$image->setImageMatte(true);
$image->compositeimage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
$image->trimimage(0);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $image;
die();
```

Comment: any ideas how to preserve the transparency of the image?